# qbittorrent error libtorrent-rasterbar.so.6 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, qbittorrent

I recently installed `qbittorrent` from the Ubuntu `Software Center` and when I try to run it I get the error:

```
qbittorrent: error while loading shared libraries: libtorrent-rasterbar.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get remove qbittorrent*
sudo apt-get purge qbittorrent*
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

but it did not help, I keep getting the same error. I should note that I upgraded from Ubuntu `12.04` to `12.10`.

What should I do? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> uninstall then reinstall libtorrent-rasterbar

https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/341#issuecomment-16332932

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error after building both libtorrent-rasterbar and qBittorrent from source.

I fixed it by running

```
sudo ldconfig
```